# MySQL - Query very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-optimization

I have statements like this that are timing out:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE A.value1 IN (
  SELECT A.value1 FROM A WHERE A.value2 = 0
)
```

Table A has 13,000,000+ rows in it, and because of some reasons, I can't use indexes.

So how to speed it up without use indexes? I'm using MySQL 5.6.

Any help please.

Comment: _because of some reasons, I can't use indexes..._ Huh? What reasons should force you to not use indexes?

Comment: afraid to slow insert,update...

Comment: _afraid to slow insert,update_ What is more important for you? Insert? Read? Update?

Comment: This sql run once a day, but insert run many times. So I prefer to not use indexes

Comment: _So I prefer to not use indexes.._ Sorry but this sounds like a technical  suicide

Answer (score 2):

I would first try using `exists`.  This often optimizes better:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM A A2
              WHERE A2.value2 = 0 AND A2.value1 = A.value1
             );
```

The optimal index for this is `A(value2, value1)`.

You could also use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(cnt)
from (select value1, count(*) as cnt
      from a
      group by value1
      having sum(value2 = 0) > 0
     ) a;
```

Comment: the second is a interesting idea